# How can I get an image resource by its name in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I want create a country and flag picker. I want to set an image of a flag, but I want to choose that image based on its name. Basically, I am trying to create a flag and ISD code picker for Android, so that I can use it for adding an ISD code before the phone number's user.

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFlag);
img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.India_91);
```

Something like this in an adapter.

```
// India_91 is an image India_91.png,
// suppose if I have USA_1.png as image then i should be able to use
// string "USA_1" to get the related resource and set it as
// BackgroundResource.

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    long resId = getResourceIdUsingResourceString(arrayOfStrings[position]);
    // I should get the Id of the image
    // resource named as"USA_91"
}

// This is a utility function outside adapter class
long getResourceIdUsingResourceString(string resourceName) {
    // Here I want to add a code which can check for
    // resource name and then get id of it
    // which can then be used by callee function/block
    // to fetch the correct resource and display it
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing piece you are looking for is `Resources.getIdentifier()`.  You can pass in the name as a String and get the integer identifier.

[Resources | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

#### Example

```
long resId = parent.getResources().getIdentifier(arrayOfStrings[position], "drawable", mApplicationContext.getPackageName());
```