# Are "compound identifiers" possible for string resources in Android?

Tags: android, string

Are "compound identifiers" possible for string resources?
Like this

```
val level = 1      <- current level
getString(R.string.answer + level)    <- and this is get (R.string.answer1) string
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the [`Resources.getIdentifier(String, String, String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method to dynamically generate the resource ID that you want, and then call `getString(int)` as normal using that generated ID.

e.g.

```
int level = 1;
String name = "answer" + level;
int stringResId = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", getPackageName());

String result = getString(stringResId);
```

See the link for Javadoc information on the parameters.

---

See related duplicates for further details, including Kotlin examples:

- [How do I get the resource id of an image if I know its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-do-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name)
- [How to get a resource id with a known resource name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-resource-name)
- [Android: How do I get string from resources using its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name)
- [How to get an image resource by it's name in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232209/how-to-get-an-image-resource-by-its-name-in-android)
- [How can I get a resource by name based on a string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840947/how-can-i-get-a-resource-by-name-based-on-a-string-variable)
- [Android, getting resource ID from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)
- [Get a string resource from "values" folder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214345/get-a-string-resource-from-values-folder-in-android)
- [Referencing a string in a string array resource with xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/referencing-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml)

Comment: Can't make work with string-array.   code -> [link](https://i.ibb.co/ZWGYZyX/2.png) string.xml -> [link](https://i.ibb.co/GWrcY7W/3.png)

Comment: @player1ykt your question did not specify string arrays, check out the newly added last link that seems to give some good solutions to the problem.